# How to add qt qmake version 4.8 to qt creator?

Tags: application-development, gcc, qt

I have Qt creator 5.4.1.I have qmake 5.4.1 but I wan to add qmake 4.8 for desktop version.How could I do?
I install gcc4.8,but I don't know Is qmake install?(if it installed so where was it?)

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hgh1# sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgomp1
  libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.8-locales g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
  gcc-4.8-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg
  libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg libstdc++-4.8-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
12 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 695 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,194 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libitm1 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [28.5 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgomp1 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [25.0 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libasan0 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [64.0 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libatomic1 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [8,288 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libquadmath0 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [187 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main g++-4.8 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [18.0 MB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gcc-4.8 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [4,909 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main cpp-4.8 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [4,444 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libstdc++-4.8-dev i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [1,060 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgcc-4.8-dev i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [1,735 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gcc-4.8-base i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [16.2 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libstdc++6 i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 [269 kB]
Fetched 30.7 MB in 4min 29s (114 kB/s)                                         
(Reading database ... 166934 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libitm1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libitm1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgomp1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgomp1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libasan0_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libasan0:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libatomic1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libquadmath0_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libquadmath0:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../g++-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking g++-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-4.8-dev:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-4.8-base_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.8-base:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up gcc-4.8-base:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
(Reading database ... 166934 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) over (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libitm1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libgomp1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libasan0:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libatomic1:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up cpp-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libgcc-4.8-dev:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up gcc-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Setting up g++-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download older versions of Qt [here](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/). I believe it will be the source though so you may have to compile it. There is a file within the same link that explains how to do this.

Once compiled, you should be able to add the older Qt version to QtCreator. Go to Tools->Options and then select "Build & Run" to add and configure the older version.